# RailsAdmin association scoping in a new field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord, rails-admin

Say I have a model Post and a model Author, and an author has_many posts. Post also has a 'state' attribute and a scope, where I can filter by Post.where(state: 'active'). In RailsAdmin, I'd like to have two fields in the Author page: posts and active_posts, where active_posts are scoped to only associated posts with an active state. I've tried the following:

```
config.model 'Author' do
  field :posts
  field :active_posts do
    formatted_value do
      bindings[:object].posts.active
    end
  end
end
```

Obviously, this won't work because this just shows an ActiveRecord Association as the formatted value.

I've also tried defining an active_posts method on the Author model, and just calling field :active_posts for config.model 'Author', but that just returns an association as well.

On the other hand, something like on the wiki (https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Associations-scoping) for association scoping isn't working at all (the posts field is showing all associated posts, not posts within the scope). Additionally, this method would only give me one Posts field that would only show active posts.

```
config.model 'Author' do
  field :posts do
    associated_collection_cache_all false 
    associated_collection_scope do
      Proc.new { |scope|
        scope = scope.where(state: 'active')
      }
    end
  end
end
```

Is there an alternative method?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up simply creating a list of links:

```
field :active_posts do
  formatted_value do
    posts = bindings[:object].posts.active
    posts.collect { |p| "<a href='/admin/post/#{p.id}'>#{p.title}</a>" }.join(", ").html_safe
  end
end
```

I wish there were a prettier way, but this works too.